# Load child class from base class

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a base class `BaseClass` with multiple subclasses `SubClass1`, `SubClass2`. In practice the program only works with instances of one of the sub-classes. The sub-classes implement an interface with the `save` method. When loading a saved element, you do not know the class you are loading. Therefore I was considering having the `load` method in the base class, but this raised the question: how do I instantiate an element from one of the sub-classes in the base class ?

```py
For clarity, here is some simple code:

    class BaseClass:
        def load(self):
            #load element of subclass
            return subclass_element

    class myInterface:
        __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
        @abstractmethod
        def save(self):
            raise NotImplementedError

    class SubClass1(BaseClass, myInterface):
        def save(self):
            #save the element

    class SubClass2(BaseClass, myInterface):
        def save(self):
            #save the element
```

I'm also open to any suggestions in favor of a different design. I'm not sure I'm not implementing an anti-pattern.

**EDIT 1: Adding a factory class**

From my understanding of what @Vishal_Raja and @Gholamali-Irani suggested:

```py
class SubClassLoader: #this is our factory class
    registered_subclasses = {} #static dict of subclasses

    @StaticMethod
    def register(classname, class):
        SubClassLoader.registered_subclasses[classname] = class

    @StaticMethod
    def get_instance(filepath):
        classname, arguments = get_classname(filepath) 
        if classname in SubClassLoader.registered_subclasses:
            return SubClassLoader.registered_subclasses[classname](arguments)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Unknown class %s" % classname)


class BaseClass:
    pass


class myInterface:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SubClass1(BaseClass, myInterface):
    def save(self):
        #save the element


class SubClass2(BaseClass, myInterface):
    def save(self):
        #save the element
```

Comment: Is this about OOP in general, or specifically about Python?

Comment: General OOP in the context of Python

Comment: But mainly general OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**:It is bad design to make a dependency from parent to child. Inheritance (of child from parent) is a type of dependency. If you add another dependency from parent to child, you make a circular dependency and it's very hard to maintain and extendable.

In Object Oriented Design Heuristics we have:

> Heuristic 5.1: Derived classes must have knowledge of their base class by definition,
>   but base classes should not know anything about their derived classes.

**Why?**

> If base classes have knowledge of their derived classes, then it is
>   implied that if a new derived class is added to a base class, the code
>   of the base class will need modification. This is an undesirable
>   dependency between the abstractions captured in the base and derived
>   classes. We will see a much better solution to these types of
>   dependencies when we discuss the topic of polymorphism later in this
>   chapter. [see reference](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/179206.Object_Oriented_Design_Heuristics)

Therefore, it is bad design to put `Load()` into parent.

**Secondly**: you said:

> when loading a saved element, you do not know the class you are loading.

So, your client only depend on `Save()` method. Therefore, their is not dependency between your client and parent. Your client only depend on the `myIntrface`.

**Finally**: your client should define an attribute from `myInterface`. Then you only need another class that inject the object to your client attribute. (like **Factory** class -as @VishalRaja's answer- or **Dependency Injector** class). Then you can put all desired configuration in it to decide which class instances should be passed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried to modify my design to use a factory as mentioned by you and @Vishal_Raja. Would you agree more with this new design ? I'm not sure I get you when you say: "your client should define an attribute from 'myInterface'", could it be possible for you to give a bit more details ?

Comment: Sorry, I used Java. In Java we can define an attribute from an Interface like:  `private myInterface x;`. Then we can set instances of any class that Implements `myInterface` to `x`.

Comment: @user3091275, There is no need to add `load()` method in subclasses or in `myInterface`. Just put it in factory class. It's better to rename it as `getInstance()`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a separate factory class which ensures the right save implementation depending on the subclass type?

Comment: The issue is not when calling the save method, but when calling the load method from the base class. Maybe you meant load instead of save?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to hint you towards a cleaner design where you can instantiate different subclasses based in a dedicated factory.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with a new design making use of a factory.